# Is there any way to store repeating foreign keys in M2M field in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I've got:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_id = models.IntegerField(default=1, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(default="None", max_length=256)

class Backpack(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

The backpack should store 6 or fewer items. But I can't add to it two the same ones.
Can I solve it somehow without 6 different foreign keys in my Backpack model?

Comment: you can use custom through model and store information about quantity
[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: order is also important to me

Comment: so add another field with order weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store how many items of given type you have in relation(through) model.

```py
class BackpackItems(models.Model):
    backpack = models.ForeignKey(Backpack, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 1)

class Item(models.Model):
    item_id = models.IntegerField(default=1, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(default="None", max_length=256)

class Backpack(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through = BackpakItems)
```

Comment: order is also important

Comment: First. Modify your question if is something important just point it. Second this method allows you put other variables like order, weight or what you need. If you need just sorted you can use [Sorted m2m](https://pypi.org/project/django-sortedm2m/)